# Cannot pass a custom adapter through a constructor

Tags: android

I have three fragment classes each with it's own custom adapter

```
//Fragment class 1
static CusomtAdapter1 adapter1;

//Fragment class 2
static CusomtAdapter2 adapter2;

//Fagment class 3
static CusomtAdapter3 adapter3;
```

All three adapters are based on the same underlying data. I want to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on all of them at the same time. So I pass them to another class.

```
//Fragment class 1
UpdateAdapters updateAdapters = new UpdateAdapters(adapter1);

//Fragment class 2
UpdateAdapters updateAdapters = new UpdateAdapters(adapter2);

//Fagment class 3
UpdateAdapters updateAdapters = new UpdateAdapters(adapter3);
```

This is is `UpdateAdapters` class

```
public class UpdateAdapters {

    private static CusomtAdapter1 adapter1;
    private static CusomtAdapter2 adapter2;
    private static CusomtAdapter3 adapter3;

    //Public Constructors
    public void UpdateAdapters(CusomtAdapter1 adapter1){
        this.adapter1 = adapter1;
    }

    public void UpdateAdapters(CusomtAdapter2 adapter2){
        this.adapter2 = adapter2;
    }

    public void UpdateAdapters(CusomtAdapter3 adapter3){
        this.adapter3 = adapter3;
    }

    //Public methods
    public static void update(){
        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And I can update them all like so

```
UpdateAdapters.update()
```

My problem is I cannot pass my adpaters to my update class

```
//Fragment class 1
UpdateAdapters updateAdapters = new UpdateAdapters(adapter1); // error: UpdateAdapters() cannot be applied to come.example.myname.myapp.CusomtAdapter1

//Fragment class 2
UpdateAdapters updateAdapters = new UpdateAdapters(adapter2); // error: UpdateAdapters() cannot be applied to come.example.myname.myapp.CusomtAdapter2

//Fagment class 3
UpdateAdapters updateAdapters = new UpdateAdapters(adapter3); // error: UpdateAdapters() cannot be applied to come.example.myname.myapp.CusomtAdapter3
```

Whats going on?

Thanks

Comment: The members of `UpdateAdapters` you have labeled `//Public Constructors` are not constructors. Since you've specified a return type on them, they're methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MikeM. pointed out, your "constructors" are basically methods. Because they are not returning an instance of objects but they return `void`. So, to get a constructor, you have to do:

```
public UpdateAdapters(...) { }
```

However, you should create one single instance for all fragments, instead of create a new one each time you set an adapter. In order to do that, you can create an instance with the following:

```
public class UpdateAdapters {
    private static UpdateAdapters instance = null;

    // constructor
    protected UpdateAdapters() { }

    // get the current instance
    public static UpdateAdapters getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            // create a new one if it doesn't exist
            instance = new UpdateAdapters();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    ...
}
```

In the fragments, when you want to add the adapters, you'll get the current instance of this object (and don't create everytime a new one) and set the adapters into it. So, you will call:

```
UpdateAdapters.getInstance().doSomething();
```

to get the current object created and to do something with this object's instance.
You could thus set the fragments' adapters. Assume you have this in UpdateAdapters class:

```
public class UpdateAdapters {
    ...
    private CusomtAdapter1 adapter1;
    private CusomtAdapter2 adapter2;
    private CusomtAdapter3 adapter3;

    public void setAdapterOne(CusomtAdapter1 adapter1) {
        this.adapter1 = adapter1;
    }

    public void setAdapterTwo(CusomtAdapter2 adapter2) {
        this.adapter2 = adapter2;
    }

    public void setAdapterThree(CusomtAdapter3 adapter3) {
        this.adapter3 = adapter3;
    }

    public void update() {
        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Then, in each fragment, you will add its adapter by using:

```
UpdateAdapters.getInstance().setAdapterOne(adapter1); // same for each one
```

And finally, update them, with the same stuff:

```
UpdateAdapters.getInstance().update();
```

Comment: Note: you can also add the adapter to a `List` in each setter method, and in `update()` do a for loop to notify all the adapter. If you will have more than three, this can be useful. *OR* maybe this might be better to extend each child adapters by one parent adapter and create an universal setter method - this should be better if you have many child adapters.